# Power supply fuses and varistor

Tags: power-supply, thermistor, varistor

I wish to build a little decent power supply for my IoT devices. I would also like to implement more protection from the live 230 V AC side and I decided to put a fast-blow glass fuse in a [nice holder](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1KqOgRpXXXXXfapXXq6xXFXXXt/10-pcs-Panel-Mount-PCB-Fuse-Holder-Case-w-Cover-5x20mm-Free-Shipping.jpg), a thermal fuse [SF70E](https://ssli.ebayimg.com/images/g/WGsAAOSwPRlXn2fT/s-l1600.jpg), and a varistor for [HLK-PM01](http://www.hlktech.net/product_detail.php?ProId=54) AC-DC 5 V/600 mA converter module.

Now the questions are:

I found an example regarding the varistor value [10D561K](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MOV-10D561K?qs=lgttKnAd%252b2ArrqGQgWwr6w%3D%3D), and I don't understand why it's not like [10D241K](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MOV-10D241K?qs=lgttKnAd%252b2CnPhE%2Fsyc8oA%3D%3D) or [10D271K](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MOV-10D271K?qs=lgttKnAd%252b2BAn0GLoYT8og%3D%3D) (this is what I have at home)?

[image]

I would make it like this:

[image]

Also for the max. 600 mA load on the DC side, what fast-blow fuse value should I use on the live 230 V AC side, 200 mA, 500 mA, 750 mA, or 1000 mA?

Comment: You may want to compute Vpeak and learn about 3kV transient test and HiPot test compliance for common mode.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yeah, but unfortunately I'm not rocket scientist like you!

Comment: But you do know how to google it right? This isn’t rocket science.  That’s why they use a 560V varistor because Vpp=2x1.414xVac (max). (RMS to Peak to peak)

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes, I read something about peak 2 peak for 230V should be 325,22Vpp, right?

Comment: Nope that’s peak not peak tp peak of the sine

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Peak-to-peak-voltage-calculator.php

Comment: 650.53V? @TonyEErocketscientist

Comment: Add 10% for service tolerance and maybe your region needs a higher bipolar MOV

Comment: Now, I would choose 10D391K but the 10D431K would be better? @TonyEErocketscientist

Comment: You can do whatever you like, but I wouldn't do that.  Do you want to understand how this works? have you done any reading yet?

Comment: If both stock items  are bipolar, you can put in series 240V +270V MOVs which is the 1mA rating for rms AC V

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Yes, I read a bunch of stuff on them, but there is only description and usage, nothing else like on the Wiki, only dry text...but, it would be easier if you tell me, should I follow the Voltage Rating DC or the Clamping Voltage from the datasheet.

Comment: i am going to rick bringing up this topic and being called thick as i have been trying to these modules for hours and i keep ending up back here at an un answered question. specifically TAS10-12-W2 i think its a 230v to 12v equivalent of the module in this thread. i am in the same situation where i do not understand enough about MOV values or AC power in general and hours of googling has made me slightly wiser but still incapable of selecting the correct values for this circuit. unusually i would just use a mains wall plug to 12v supply but i require a simple way of including this on my PCB

Comment: @JayDee Yeah, I'm still waiting also... (sad story), but true!

Comment: waiting for?  how to choose a 560 V bipolar MOV for > +/- 560 V clamping where part number ends in 561 which means 56 + 1 zero

Comment: @beic i no its a bit time overdue but i hope this helps you since it cost me 50 xp points for some answers :-) i suggest waiting another 3 days for the bounty to end and then select the best answer for your needs and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Two Questions:
**Q1 - about MOV selection**:

> I found an example regarding the varistor value **10D561K**, and I don't understand why it's not like **10D241K** or **10D271K** (this is what I have at home)?

**Q2 - about Fast blow fuse selection**:

> Also for the max. 600 mA load on the DC side, what fast-blow fuse value should I use on the live 230 V AC side, 200 mA, 500 mA, 750 mA, or 1000 mA?

### Q1 - Adequate MOV:

From the link you already provided, you have a power supply from Hi-Link, powered by 230V AC.
That “230V” is the “effective or DC equivalent” voltage, and as is an AC voltage, the mean values are expressed in **RMS** values, where [RMS is explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square).
**About AC supply voltage**: Also, supply voltages have a nominal value, but are considered acceptable with a given % of dispersion around this nominal value, which usually is +/- 10% in well-designed and operated providers.
Using +10% over 230VAC, maximum operating voltages would be **243VAC** (RMS).

**About the MOV Datasheet**: following table, from [Bourns (Mouser)](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/mov10d-777448.pdf):

- **Maximum Continuous operating voltage** - Left Blue column marks the RMS value. Your AC (RMS) values shall be lower than this.
- **Nominal Rated Voltage** - Right blue column. Voltage where the MOV conducts a small current of 1mA. If a MOV rated for 560V as 10D561K, is submitted to 560V, it will pass 1mA, dissipating then **560mW**.
  However, a **MOV with “size” 10D** can **dissipate up to 0.4W** (400mW) so, even for the rated leak current of 1mA, it will overheat and be destroyed, probably in a few minutes!
- **MOVs 241K** and **271K** - those you have. Boxed in **Red**, because they are adequate for 110/127VAC applications only. The operating voltage will leak current at 230VAC, and even more at 243VAC. In both cases, the current will be higher than 1mA, being destroyed in seconds! They are NOT RECOMMENDED for VAC > 150VAC RMS.
- **MOV 561K** - boxed in **Thick Orange**. They are rated to operate continuously up to 350VAC RMS. In this case, they are not destroyed by an overvoltage, but the rated value is too high to make them a protection device for more sensitive appliances.
- **MOV 431K** - highlighted in **Green**. This is the MOV more often seen for bi-volt devices (100~240VAC), as it provides a good safety margin to not be tripped inadvertently by normal operational voltage fluctuations, but will protect any eventual higher-voltage spike.
- **MOVs 361K** and **391K**, boxed in *thin-lined* **Orange**. Not recommended, as there is not a large-enough safety margin if combined lower rated voltage of MOV with higher supply-voltage tolerance as **243VACrms** resulting in **343Vpeak**. See inbox in gray background.

[image]

**Summary of Q1 answer**:
Not recommended to use 241K or 271K for 230VAC, as it will be damaged and cause harm. These MOVs are ok for 100-130VAC only.
MOV 561K will withstand well but protects less than other MOV ratings. Not recommended because of that (almost useless).
*Recommended to use MOV 10D431K*.

### Q2 - Selection of a Fast-Acting Fuse:

**About the Hi-Link Power Module**:
The link you provided was broken, but I found the [HLK-PM01 here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1909111105_HI-LINK-HLK-PM24_C399250.pdf).
From, it, we can see the input section has the following features:

[image]

Observe that maximum current is I.max </= 200 mA, for rated voltages from 90-245 VAC. As this is a Switched-mode Power supply, it is expected to use about half at 230VAC. In this case:
**I(@230VAC) </= 100mA**. Let's hold this datum for a while.

About slow blow fuse:
[image]

Source: [Farnell’s 500mA search](https://uk.farnell.com/c/circuit-protection/fuses-fuse-accessories/fuses/cartridge-fuses?blow-characteristic=slow-blow&fuse-current=500ma) and [this selection](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/LFSI/LFSI-S-A0001360551/LFSI-S-A0001360551-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0).
For a Slow-blow fuse, 500mA rated, during inrush specified as 50 ms, it trips at 9A - arrows in Black and Brown.

**About the Fast-blow Fuse**:
From [Farnell datasheet here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1859200.pdf), I extracted the following graph to highlight some features.

For the steady-state current only, a 200mA (**green** line) would suffice for 100-240VAC. Maybe even a 100mA (**red** line) would work for operation at 230VAC only, but most probably it will blow during startup.

**Inrush current is the relevant problem** for the desired fast-acting fuse.
Here, an important assumption is that for *your application* the envelope that "trips" a slow-blow fuse and fast-blow fuse will be leveled.  In this case, the 50 ms (blue arrow) and 9A (Brown arrow) points to a **2A rated** fast-acting fuse.

**Summary of Q2 answer**:
The best guess would be to **use a 2A fast-acting glass fuse to "mimic"** the behavior of a slow-blow 500mA fuse - for *your application*.

[image]

**Additional suggestion - use an inrush 120R NTC**:
If you use an inrush NTC current, as searched in [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/c/circuit-protection/thermistors/inrush-current-limiting-icl-ntc-thermistors?st=120) and [here](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2131310.pdf), it can be seen it will operate with up to 1.5A and 230VAC.  In this case, the start will be softer, and most probably a smaller-rated fast-acting fuse as 500mA  would work.

Comment: Keep in mind that Thermal Fuse SF70E, if still used and if the Inrush NTC suggest is implemented, the NTC should **not be close to thermal fuse - better being explicit and safe than sorry.

Comment: Thermal Fuse SF70E would be placed by the middle of the HLK-PM01 and bent to it, and regarding the NTC, could I replace the Farnell's with this NTC 120D-15? Thanks!

Comment: If I understood you correctly, no - it is *not to replace the Fast-Acting fuse by an NTC*. The NTC is used to limit the inrush current, mimicking the Slow-blow fuse at startup. Keep the fuse.  A **’Polyfuse’** is a particular PTC component that could be sized to replace the fuse. But that is another matter/question.   About the thermal fuse, I believe it’s gain can be marginal at 70°C and may be affected by environmental conditions (summer) - but this depends where it is to be used and housed.

Comment: You didn't understand me correctly, you mentioned to add an additional 120R ICL NTC to the circuit, so, I asked about the NTC model 120D-15, is it suitable for my needs? (I don't want to replace nothing, just to add the new ICL NTC what you mentioned)

Comment: Now your intent is clear. The 120D from TDK or from Farnell’s search engine did not have 15mm disk, just 11.5mm (‘10’ nominal). From this 11.5mm and 120R cold resistance, at its maximum current (1.5A & 250°C) it shows 0.99R. The voltage drop will be somewhere between 12V (cold) and 0.1V (hotttest). At 0.1A < I < 0.2A, hot resistance of 120D-10 may be around few Ohm, I guess; so actual voltages seen by your Hi-Link would be fine.  To be ‘100%’ sure, check similarly for your 15mm Inrush NTC and its corresponding datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

> I found an example regarding the varistor value 10D561K, and I don't understand why it's not like 10D241K or 10D271K (this is what I have at home)?

The 10D271K is rated for 175Vrms (175VAC). It would be acceptable for 120VAC mains like in US or Japan. The "270V" rating is for DC voltage. It doesn't apply for AC.

Instead, you should get a part rated for 240VAC + 15%, since 240 is only the nominal line voltage, but transient faults in the distribution system can bring it up easily 15% higher than nominal, yet still should *not* trigger the MOV. 240VAC+15%=276VAC. Thus, MOV-10D431K with 275VAC rating would be adequate.