# A ceramic capacitor on my PC SMPS has blown; need to identify it

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, identification, ceramic

I have a Cooler Master 600 W SMPS Model no. RS-600-pcar-E3. Recently I tried to switch on my motherboard and I heard something burst and saw sparks before it stopped working.

After opening it I got a smell from near the transformer and noticed a ceramic capacitor was completely blown in half. I was able to delsolder it, but I can only read the first digit "2". It's a orange-ish color.

My knowledge of electronics is minimal and I'm trying to make sense of what type of ratings are on this. I've attached an image of where it is located. From my understanding it's on the primary side, but I could be wrong as this is all new to me.

I was considering trying a few ceramic capacitors with "2" as the first digit, but how critical and sensitive is its role in the circuit likely to be?

The model number on the PCB is 4CEM-94VO E237305.

[image: SMPS Overview]

[image: Close up of desoldered area]

Comment: Without a (reversed engineered) schematic, this is just guesswork...

Comment: A capacitor that small is likely to be something like a bootstrap capacitor for one of the MOSFETs, and the failure may actually be in the H-bridge. It should be easy enough to check the MOSFETs for shorts, and you could trace the pins to the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, that was **not** a ceramic capacitor, since they rarely go 'bang' (despite the indication C48). Hopefully, if placed across the power transformer, the deceased device was a [metal oxide varistor, MOV,](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/varistor.html), which looks much like a ceramic cap, but provides over-voltage protection, instead. If so, it died to protect the circuit from a voltage spike, but in this case, seems to have failed to prevent damage, or it may have succeeded by blowing a fuse, as intended.

As others mentioned, without a schematic, it's impossible to be sure which it was, or what destroyed it. Simply replacing it would not fix the issue.

**If** there is a series fuse, as [shown in this StackExchange schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383981/power-supply-fuses-and-varistor), then that would need to be replaced for the PS to work, and any MOV should be replaced as well, to protect the supply. If there was no fuse, then likely the PS has become a boat anchor, since replacing the transformer would not be worth its cost.

In any event, try to determine what caused a voltage surge so powerful as to destroy a MOV or capacitor before other equipment is harmed, or starts a fire. Was there a nearby lightning strike? A broken neutral on the AC mains entrance cable? A fault in the AC power distribution system? It would also be a good idea to use [surge protectors](https://www.cnet.com/tech/home-entertainment/10-shocking-facts-about-power-strips/) on all AC mains outlets to help avoid future issues. [At my house, we *have* experienced a broken neutral, but surge-protected power strips prevented damage to a PC - the MOV in the strip was a charred mess, though.]

Comment: If the comment in the picture is correct, it is designated **C**48 tough, implying a capacitor.

Comment: Oops! Thanks, @Unimportant, I'd missed that vital piece, and will amend the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but aren't MOV marked as something other than C? I have double checked it is C48 indeed. I guess without schematics this is anybodys guess so I'll just try a few capacitors like 224, 225 and if it blows I'm just gonna get a new SMPS